# Issue with using 'extends' and 'super' in java generics with generic methods

Tags: java, generics, collections

There is a method :

`public static <T> void addandDisp(Collection<T> cs, T t)`

which is being called in the following way :

```
List<? extends Object> ls2 = new LinkedList<Number>();
addandDisp(ls2,new Object());
```

This gives a compile time error. On the other hand, **if we had only one parameter**, then the call is successful. Why is that ?

Moreover, this is successful :

```
List<? super String> ls1 = new LinkedList<String>();
addandDisp(ls1,new String());
```

while this is not :

```
List<? super String> ls1 = new LinkedList<Object>();
addandDisp(ls1,new Object());
```

What is the underlying logic ?

Comment: _If we had only one parameter_ Which one? Either? Consider the type inferred.

Comment: If the method signature had only 'Collection<T> cs' as the argument, the above call works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On the other hand, if we had only one parameter, then the call is successful. Why is that ?

Your method has a single type parameter. When you invoke a method, you either provide a type argument explicitly or have one be inferred implicitly.

When you invoke it like

```
addandDisp(ls2, new Object());
```

the compiler needs to extract a type to bind to `T` from both method arguments, since both method parameters rely on the method's type parameter, `T`.

The issue here is that `? extends Object` and `Object` do not produce a single type that can be bound to `T` safely. Imagine you had

```
public static <T> void addandDisp(Collection<T> cs, T t) {
    cs.add(t);
}
...
List<? extends Object> ls2 = new LinkedList<Number>();
addandDisp(ls2, new Object());
```

This `add` should not be allowed since an `Object` should not be used where a `Number` would have been expected. Type safety would break.

If you have a single parameter

```
public static <T> void addandDisp(Collection<T> cs) {
```

Then the compiler uses the single argument to infer the type argument. There is then no ambiguity about what to use.

Answer (score 11):

I would assume that `addandDisp` means *add and display*.

When you have a collection, defined as:

```
List<? extends Object> ls2 = new LinkedList<Number>();
```

This means that the compiler will allow you to assign the colletion to all the possible **unknown subtypes** of `Object`. Since you have the operation `add`, the compiler denies to give you green light, because it doesn't know if the provided object's type meets the restriction to be of the **unknown subtype** of Object. This is called *covariance*.

---

Similary, when you have a definition like this:

```
List<? super String> ls1 = new LinkedList<String>();
```

The compiler allows you to assing `ls1` to:

- `LinkedList<String>(); //you can add Strings to the list`
- `LinkedList<Object>(); //you can add Strings and Objects to the list`

In this case, the compiler will be completely aware if the object you're trying to pass meets the condition to be subtype of the generic type of the collection. This is called *contravariance*.

More info:

- [What is PECS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs)

Comment: In the case of 'extend', Why does the call succeed if the method has only the collection parameter. Why does adding a second parameter force it to fail ?

Comment: Well...by definition, collections can be parametrized with only one type. Or I don't understand what are you asking...

Comment: I am calling 'addandDisp' with 2 parameters in the example in the question, and getting the errors. These errors don't come if the method signature takes only a single parameter i.e. only 'Collection<T> cs'

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach, but others gave a quite detailed response.

**The first example:**

```
List<? extends Object> ls0 = new LinkedList<Number>();
addandDisp(ls0, new Object());
```

Here `ls0` may be of any type that is a subclass of `Object`, like a `Number` as your example shows.

Now what if this could work? It would mean that if you can put an `Object` into any of the collections.

Imagine I want to iterate your previous list of `Number` objects:

```
for (Number n : numbers) {
    ...
}
```

If I could put an `Object` here, then *Plaff!* I would get a class cast exception immediately.

**The second example**

```
List<? super String> ls1 = ...;
addandDisp(ls1,new String());
```

Let's play a bit with the object hierarchy: `String` is a subclass of `CharSequence` which is a subclass of `Object`.

You get `ls1` here which is an unknown supertype of String (e.g., a `CharSequence`). Is it all right to put a `String` into a list of character sequences? Yup, it's okay, since they share the same interface for sure! You can handle them through it in the same way.

**The third example**

```
List<? super String> ls1 = ...;
addandDisp(ls1,new Object());
```

Let's suppose the previous situation: you assign `ls1` a list of `CharSequence`s. Can you add an object to a `List<CharSequence>`? Nope, for the same reason as the first example fails.

Hope that helps clarifying your issues a bit :-)

Answer (score 0):

1 example: `Object` is not `? extends Object` (for example, `Number` is `? extends Object`, but `Object` is not `Number`). Thus, it is not type safe.

2 example: `String` is `? super String`. It is type safe.

3 example: `Object` is not `? super String`. Not safe again.

Comment: Object is the superclass of String, though. Mind elaborating on what you mean? If String extends object, then wouldn't Object be suitable for `? super String`?

Comment: @VinceEmigh ? super String is unknown type which is a super type of String. String is a super type of String. Object is not String.